# Problems reading a file in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a file in c using fread, but fread didn't show all records, only a few.
Note that i write the file using struct and recover the same way. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data{
    int numero;
};

void read(){
    int i = 1;
    FILE *arquivo = fopen(URL_NEW, "r");
    struct data dataTemp;

    fseek(arquivo,sizeof(struct data),SEEK_SET);

    int leitura;
    while (fread(&dataTemp,1,sizeof(struct data),arquivo))
    {   
        printf("\nNumber = ");
        printf("%d\n",dataTemp.numero);
    }

    fclose(arquivo);        
}

void write(){
    struct data dataTemp;
    FILE *arquivo = fopen(URL_NEW, "w");

    for(int i=1; i < 2000;i++){
        dataTemp.numero = i;

        fwrite(&dataTemp,sizeof(struct data),1,arquivo);
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
}

int main(){
    write();
    read();
}


output:

Number = 2
Number = 3
Number = 4
Number = 5
Number = 6
Number = 7
Number = 8
Number = 9
Number = 10
Number = 11
Number = 12
Number = 13
Number = 14
Number = 15
Number = 16
Number = 17
Number = 18
Number = 19
Number = 20
Number = 21
Number = 22
Number = 23
Number = 24
Number = 25
```

If i try to to use fseek, they got lost at 10 record. Anyone know know i can fix it or any workaround for my problem?

EDIT: Seems like using rb and wb fixed the problem, thanks! :D

Comment: `fssek` is not necessary. Also use `"rb"` and `"wb"` instead of `"r"` and `"w"`.

Comment: You're skipping over the first record with the `fseek()`.

Comment: I tried your program, it printed from 2 to 1999.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That wouldn't explain why it stops at `Number = 25`, though. If that were the problem, he'd get garbage starting at `Number = 10`, because it will add an extra byte before it to write CRLF.

Comment: Yeah, i've tried using rb and wb and seems to work. Thanks

Comment: @Barmar I don't believe the output example so much. :-)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY He says he's not getting all the output he expects, so I thought the example was all he's getting.

Comment: Are you running on Windows or Unix? On Unix it doesn't matter if you use the `b` mode, but Windows needs it for binary files.

Comment: @Barmar I think it is omitted because it is too long.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Then what do you think he means by "fread didn't show all records, only a few"?

Comment: @Barmar I think that it means that the first record is missing. lost 1 record, not 10 records. At least the example output seems like.

Comment: Man just think what You r doing, You save whole structure in text mode and reading it again in text mode it cannot succeed, you will get special characters translation and data will be corrupted.

Comment: it is poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being used.  I.E. stdlib.h and string.h

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fseek(), always check (==0) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the `URL_NEW` is undefined.  it should contain (or be) a char string

Comment: in the `read()` function, this statement: `int i = 1;` is not used and should be removed.   similar considerations apply to: `int leitura;`

Answer (score -1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for errors
4. does not use well known system function names for local functions
   however, `read()` and `write()` are prototyped in `unistd.h` so not a direct problem with the code as that header file is not included.

the reason it did not work (well there are a few reasons)

most notably, the compiler will output several warning and error messages.
It is a wonder that it ever ran.

When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.

(for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-wall -wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11`  I also use: `-Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -ggdb )

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // perror(), fopen(), FILE, fseek(), fread(), printf(), fclose()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
//#include <string.h>

struct data
{
    int numero;
};


// prototypes
void myRead( void );
void myWrite( void );


void myRead()
{

    FILE *arquivo = fopen("/tmp/URL_NEW", "r");
    if( !arquivo )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read URL_NEW failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    struct data dataTemp;

    // the following 'fseek()' skips over the first record
    if( 0 != fseek(arquivo, sizeof(struct data), SEEK_SET) )
    {
        perror( "fseek failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fseek successful


    // note: the returned value and the third parameter must match
    while ( 1 == fread(&dataTemp, sizeof(struct data), 1, arquivo))
    {
        printf("\nNumber = ");
        printf("%d\n", dataTemp.numero);
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
} // end function: myRead()


void myWrite()
{
    struct data dataTemp;
    FILE *arquivo = fopen("/tmp/URL_NEW", "w");
    if( !arquivo )
    {
        perror( "fopen to write URL_NEW failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    for(int i=1; i < 2000;i++)
    {
        dataTemp.numero = i;

        // note: the returned value and the third parameter must match
        if( 1 != fwrite(&dataTemp, sizeof(struct data), 1, arquivo) )
        {
            perror( "fwrite failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fwrite successful
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
}

int main( void )
{
    myWrite();
    myRead();
}
```

a sample of the early and late output:

```
Number = 2 

Number = 3

Number = 4

....

Number = 1996

Number = 1997

Number = 1998

Number = 1999
```

Comment: this was compiled, linked, executed on a linux 16.04 OS using `gcc`

Comment: Recommend to open in _binary_ mode rather than _text_ mode with `fopen("/tmp/URL_NEW", "rb");`  (add `b`),

Comment: @chux, as mentioned in a comment to the OPs question, on linux, the 'b' has no effect.